# UUID column value not available until a model reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with a `:uuid` column set up by the following migration.

```
add_column :website, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()"
```

It seems that the UUID isn't generated until I reload a newly created website.

```
website = Website.create!(host: 'example.com')
website.uuid
# => nil
website.reload
# => "de76e1c0-ac4a-4da6-8baf-8b9f037d39b1"
```

Is there a way to make the UUID available without having to reload?

Comment: uuid is an extension - you have to install it to use it. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

Comment: I have it installed, I'm using it and it's working. It's just not working until I reload the object.

Comment: Wanted to add that the uuid field does not populate if you don't add default: "uuid_generate_v4()" or if you replace it with index: true.

Comment: @DavidTuite did you ever find out the answer? This is strange behaviour. When I used the postgres uuid extension with Rails (once upon a time) I did not experience this, although I will note we didn't use the `default` like you are. I'd be curious to know if this problem simply went away with a Rails upgrade or continues, because I'm considering using this column type again in an upcoming project.

Answer (score 11):

I also stumbled on this. Found this [closed issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17605) in Rails, maintainers basically saying "this is intended" (great, thanks).

I ended up using something similar to the workaround described near the bottom, here's my snippet:

```rb
after_commit :reload_uuid, on: :create

def reload_uuid
  self[:uuid] = self.class.where(id: id).pluck(:uuid).first
end
```

I don't bother checking if it has a uuid attribute because I only add this to my classes with uuid's and I use `after_commit` because why bother getting the uuid if some other callback causes the save to fail?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, 'not that I know of' ... so. No.

Only way to avoid this is not delegate UUID generation to the DB via `uuid_generate_v4()` and generate it on Ruby/Rails side using something like `SecureRandom.uuid`. A callback like `before_save` would do.

I guess it was a design decision on ActiveModel not to reload after save for performance reasons. I mean, you could do it if you want to, but not assume that's the case for all scenarios (from their POV) ... so ActiveModel just returns the object that it last had to avoid the trip to the DB.